# Wordpress blog posts not displaying

Tags: wordpress, blogs

Wordpress blog is not displaying, I have Essential Grid installed but not being used for posts, getting this error message when trying to add a new blog post.

Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 11 in /home/easydays/public_html/photoexpressions.ca/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/autoload/hook-vc-grid.php on line 162

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/easydays/public_html/photoexpressions.ca/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/autoload/hook-vc-grid.php:162) in /home/easydays/public_html/photoexpressions.ca/wp-admin/admin-header.php on line 9

Comment: Judging by the error messages, there appears to be an issue with the js_composer plugin. It could be a compatibility issue between that plugin and another plugin, or your site's theme. Best bet is to disable all plugins, switch to the twentytwenty theme that comes with WordPress, and attempt to create a blog post. If that works, start enabling plugins one by one until you get the error again, in order to narrow down the culprit.

Comment: If you can't access the dashboard to deactivate the plugin, rename the js_composer plugin folder via FTP and then you should be able to get in.